# Substitute integer number in the list with multiple 1

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new to Mathematica, still trying to familiarise myself with the language.

I have a list: `{2,3,4}`. How can I change it to `{{1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1,1}}`?

Comment: Also `{2,3,4}//TakeList[ConstantArray[1, Total@#],#]&`

Answer (score 11):

You can do it like this for example:

```
ConstantArray[1,#]&/@{2,3,4}
```

*{{1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}*

Comment: That's perfect works! Thank you!

Comment: other options, just for fun: `ArrayReshape[{1}, {#}, 1] & /@ {2, 3, 4}`, `PadRight[{1}, #, 1] & /@ {2, 3, 4}`, `Table[1, #] & /@ {2, 3, 4}`, ...

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way:

```
list = {2, 3, 4};
Sign[Range[list]]
{{1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

(with a little simplification from @AccidentalFourierTransform)

Comment: simpler: `Sign[Range[list]]`, or `1 + 0 Range[{2, 3, 4}]`.

Comment: @bill s, `Unitize` seems to be cleaner ))).